# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target with diffrent java version

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, keycloak

I have generated below certificates for keycloak

```
keytool -genkey -alias ckey -keyalg  RSA  -keystore keycloak.jks  -validity 365  -keysize 2048
```

and then export those certificates

```
keytool -export -noprompt -trustcacerts -keystore keycloak.jks -alias ckey -file keycloak.cer -storepass keycloak
```

and after this used same certificates in client machine and added in Java

```
 keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "ckey" -file keycloak.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Now when i am trying to run my web-application through JbossEAP6.4

The only difference is Java provided and version in the machine where i created certificates i am using

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_102"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

While in client machine i am using

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

Can someone please help me what i am doing wrong? Is Java provider create a issue in my case?

Edit 1 After adding  `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

> 20:05:57,201 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, setSoTimeout(0) called
>
> 20:05:58,213 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Allow unsafe
>   renegotiation: false 20:05:58,213 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Allow legacy hello messages: true 20:05:58,213
>   INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Is initial handshake: true
>   20:05:58,213 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Is secure
>   renegotiation: false
>
> 20:05:58,228 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1
>
> 20:05:58,228 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1
>
> 20:05:58,228 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
>
> 20:05:58,228 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1
>
> 20:05:58,228 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1
>
> 20:05:58,229 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1
>
> 20:05:58,229 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1.1
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1.1
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1.1
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1.1
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1.1
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Ignoring
>   unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for
>   TLSv1.1
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) %% No cached client
>   session
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) *** ClientHello,
>   TLSv1.2
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) RandomCookie:  GMT:
>   1515594702 bytes = { 90, 0, 246, 90, 118, 113, 12, 213, 54, 196, 191,
>   113, 210, 173, 116, 104, 204, 113, 143, 206, 237, 122, 188, 179, 31,
>   215, 154, 66 }
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Session ID:  {}
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Cipher Suites:
>   [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Compression
>   Methods:  { 0 }
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Extension
>   elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1,
>   sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1,
>   secp256k1}
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Extension
>   ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Extension
>   signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA,
>   SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA,
>   SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ***
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) [write] MD5 and
>   SHA1 hashes:  len = 161
>
> 20:05:58,230 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0000: 01 00 00 9D
>   03 03 5A 56   24 CE 5A 00 F6 5A 76 71  ......ZV$.Z..Zvq
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0010: 0C D5 36 C4
>   BF 71 D2 AD   74 68 CC 71 8F CE ED 7A  ..6..q..th.q...z
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0020: BC B3 1F D7
>   9A 42 00 00   3A C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  .....B..:.#.'.<.
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0030: 25 C0 29 00
>   67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0040: 0E 00 33 00
>   32 C0 2B C0   2F 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00  ..3.2.+./...-.1.
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0050: 9E 00 A2 C0
>   08 C0 12 00   0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00  ................
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0060: 13 00 FF 01
>   00 00 3A 00   0A 00 16 00 14 00 17 00  ......:.........
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0070: 18 00 19 00
>   09 00 0A 00   0B 00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00  ................
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0080: 16 00 0B 00
>   02 01 00 00   0D 00 16 00 14 06 03 06  ................
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0090: 01 05 03 05
>   01 04 03 04   01 04 02 02 03 02 01 02  ................
>
> 20:05:58,245 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00A0: 02
>   .
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 161
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) [Raw write]: length
>   = 166
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0000: 16 03 03 00
>   A1 01 00 00   9D 03 03 5A 56 24 CE 5A  ...........ZV$.Z
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0010: 00 F6 5A 76
>   71 0C D5 36   C4 BF 71 D2 AD 74 68 CC  ..Zvq..6..q..th.
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0020: 71 8F CE ED
>   7A BC B3 1F   D7 9A 42 00 00 3A C0 23  q...z.....B..:.#
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0030: C0 27 00 3C
>   C0 25 C0 29   00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13  .'.<.%.).g.@....
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0040: 00 2F C0 04
>   C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 2B C0 2F 00 9C  ./.....3.2.+./..
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0050: C0 2D C0 31
>   00 9E 00 A2   C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03  .-.1............
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0060: C0 0D 00 16
>   00 13 00 FF   01 00 00 3A 00 0A 00 16  ...........:....
>
> 20:05:58,261 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0070: 00 14 00 17
>   00 18 00 19   00 09 00 0A 00 0B 00 0C  ................
>
> 20:05:58,277 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0080: 00 0D 00 0E
>   00 16 00 0B   00 02 01 00 00 0D 00 16  ................
>
> 20:05:58,277 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0090: 00 14 06 03
>   06 01 05 03   05 01 04 03 04 01 04 02  ................
>
> 20:05:58,277 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00A0: 02 03 02 01
>   02 02                                  ......
>
> 20:05:58,433 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) [Raw read]: length
>   = 5
>
> 20:05:58,433 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0000: 16 03 03 05
>   37                                     ....7
>
> 20:05:58,433 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) [Raw read]: length
>   = 1335
>
> 20:05:58,433 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0000: 02 00 00 4D
>   03 03 5A 56   24 CE 0C A9 A5 B8 CA 42  ...M..ZV$......B
>
> 20:05:58,433 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0010: AC 4F CD 89
>   78 9B 54 35   60 9B AB CC 1B 9E 6E CC  .O..x.T5`.....n.
>
> 20:05:58,433 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0020: 1E 6A 33 42
>   2D 65 20 5A   56 24 CE 8B 7F F5 8A 4C  .j3B-e ZV$.....L
>
> 20:05:58,433 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0030: 10 35 40 DD
>   6A F3 D2 D6   DC 68 B1 D8 E4 6F F8 BD  .5@.j....h...o..
>
> 20:05:58,433 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0040: 56 27 42 A6
>   7F BC 34 C0   27 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  V'B...4.'.......
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0050: 00 0B 00 03
>   91 00 03 8E   00 03 8B 30 82 03 87 30  ...........0...0
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0060: 82 02 6F A0
>   03 02 01 02   02 04 77 5A F1 CF 30 0D  ..o.......wZ..0.
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0070: 06 09 2A 86
>   48 86 F7 0D   01 01 0B 05 00 30 74 31  ..*.H........0t1
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0080: 10 30 0E 06
>   03 55 04 06   13 07 55 6E 6B 6E 6F 77  .0...U....Unknow
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0090: 6E 31 10 30
>   0E 06 03 55   04 08 13 07 55 6E 6B 6E  n1.0...U....Unkn
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00A0: 6F 77 6E 31
>   10 30 0E 06   03 55 04 07 13 07 55 6E  own1.0...U....Un
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00B0: 6B 6E 6F 77
>   6E 31 10 30   0E 06 03 55 04 0A 13 07  known1.0...U....
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00C0: 55 6E 6B 6E
>   6F 77 6E 31   10 30 0E 06 03 55 04 0B  Unknown1.0...U..
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00D0: 13 07 55 6E
>   6B 6E 6F 77   6E 31 18 30 16 06 03 55  ..Unknown1.0...U
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00E0: 04 03 13 0F
>   31 33 35 2E   32 35 30 2E 31 33 39 2E  ....135.250.139.
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00F0: 31 30 39 30
>   1E 17 0D 31   38 30 31 30 39 31 32 30  1090...180109120
>
> 20:05:58,449 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0100: 31 35 36 5A
>   17 0D 31 39   30 31 30 39 31 32 30 31  156Z..1901091201
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0110: 35 36 5A 30
>   74 31 10 30   0E 06 03 55 04 06 13 07  56Z0t1.0...U....
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0120: 55 6E 6B 6E
>   6F 77 6E 31   10 30 0E 06 03 55 04 08  Unknown1.0...U..
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0130: 13 07 55 6E
>   6B 6E 6F 77   6E 31 10 30 0E 06 03 55  ..Unknown1.0...U
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0140: 04 07 13 07
>   55 6E 6B 6E   6F 77 6E 31 10 30 0E 06  ....Unknown1.0..
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0150: 03 55 04 0A
>   13 07 55 6E   6B 6E 6F 77 6E 31 10 30  .U....Unknown1.0
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0160: 0E 06 03 55
>   04 0B 13 07   55 6E 6B 6E 6F 77 6E 31  ...U....Unknown1
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0170: 18 30 16 06
>   03 55 04 03   13 0F 31 33 35 2E 32 35  .0...U....135.25
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0180: 30 2E 31 33
>   39 2E 31 30   39 30 82 01 22 30 0D 06  0.139.1090.."0..
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0190: 09 2A 86 48
>   86 F7 0D 01   01 01 05 00 03 82 01 0F  .*.H............
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 01A0: 00 30 82 01
>   0A 02 82 01   01 00 90 39 67 6B B7 DC  .0.........9gk..
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 01B0: 48 0E 2E E4
>   6B CC F3 DD   21 EF BC 8B C1 2D 29 63  H...k...!....-)c
>
> 20:05:58,465 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 01C0: 49 31 6E 2A
>   F4 93 BA C8   CB 10 7C 28 28 3C 47 CD  I1n*.......((
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 01D0: E2 EF B4 8F
>   6B 31 FB 16   01 FD 19 BA 6F E2 F5 F9  ....k1......o...
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 01E0: BF E8 59 88
>   9E BE 43 5A   D0 F2 4A 0F 52 B4 F6 6E  ..Y...CZ..J.R..n
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 01F0: C1 D8 5E BF
>   4A 2D 6C 97   A1 AA AF 96 39 6E B9 45  ..^.J-l.....9n.E
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0200: 7B 03 EB B2
>   DA FA E1 83   4B D6 F7 62 6C BA BA 74  ........K..bl..t
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0210: FB BC 1E 28
>   93 19 F9 1F   2B E0 AC 85 85 0C F1 8B  ...(....+.......
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0220: 85 F4 2C 0C
>   09 6A 81 A7   7C E8 36 C2 DF 21 3D 62  ..,..j....6..!=b
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0230: 82 AC 44 54
>   9C 82 BD EB   6C 09 93 6B 85 83 E1 9E  ..DT....l..k....
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0240: 7E 41 D8 2E
>   2C AD B3 3C   49 0A C8 A3 E1 E7 90 E3  .A..,..
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0250: AB 24 16 49
>   17 74 3B AE   4A 03 5F E3 2A 4C 48 49  .$.I.t;.J._.*LHI
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0260: D1 B3 A5 7E
>   05 D3 3C 1E   7B D0 B5 92 AF 47 0B 05  ......<......G..
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0270: 60 52 E1 FF
>   F4 31 D7 5C   BA EE B3 3F E5 E6 4E 8D  `R...1....?..N.
>
> 20:05:58,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0280: 26 1E CE 30
>   F7 6E 03 69   78 F5 9A A8 C3 B3 E4 9C  &..0.n.ix.......
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0290: 26 B4 F3 CF
>   2D CB 75 80   65 28 FA CC 71 90 19 FB  &...-.u.e(..q...
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 02A0: D8 09 09 37
>   89 3E C8 57   73 A9 02 03 01 00 01 A3  ...7.>.Ws.......
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 02B0: 21 30 1F 30
>   1D 06 03 55   1D 0E 04 16 04 14 B6 C2  !0.0...U........
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 02C0: 19 D4 9C FD
>   3F EA 54 87   B7 42 E1 0D 8A 95 F8 99  ....?.T..B......
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 02D0: AE ED 30 0D
>   06 09 2A 86   48 86 F7 0D 01 01 0B 05  ..0...*.H.......
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 02E0: 00 03 82 01
>   01 00 5D 0E   55 1F C3 1B B5 72 37 F7  ......].U....r7.
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 02F0: 2F EF 1D 85
>   AD D2 8C 92   81 BF 54 6C 3E E2 64 30  /.........Tl>.d0
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0300: 05 D8 77 AE
>   D0 19 B7 79   6D 1F 9A AC D7 92 79 72  ..w....ym.....yr
>
> 20:05:58,496 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0310: 67 82 FB CC
>   F2 00 37 2F   0A E9 26 34 FF 37 83 DC  g.....7/..&4.7..
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0320: 38 C0 5B 6D
>   A8 E5 D4 9B   A4 E5 AE 77 EA 93 12 FD  8.[m.......w....
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0330: 00 9A 4A 0A
>   9C 63 E4 67   9F F1 05 BD D5 C7 DF 0E  ..J..c.g........
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0340: FC 17 30 50
>   92 83 33 00   9B E9 A1 90 E4 32 C4 00  ..0P..3......2..
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0350: 76 A9 05 36
>   07 6C 00 19   65 0C 2B 8C 89 28 FF E4  v..6.l..e.+..(..
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0360: F0 67 B2 2C
>   6B D3 9B 48   DB 18 10 EF F5 BF 3B 9C  .g.,k..H......;.
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0370: D0 19 F1 1E
>   59 39 36 04   F4 D9 91 25 77 3C 95 13  ....Y96....%w<..
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0380: AC A9 61 3F
>   E9 B2 AC 66   F2 95 2C F5 3A C2 8A BC  ..a?...f..,.:...
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0390: AC C6 B3 68
>   AC A5 33 72   4C 88 97 F7 50 1D 70 5B  ...h..3rL...P.p[
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 03A0: FD 1D FF 19
>   F4 18 1A 1B   3D 8D 57 4B 23 F1 7F 3A  ........=.WK#..:
>
> 20:05:58,512 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 03B0: 55 95 1E 82
>   F6 D2 DD EB   9B 99 BE 2C 46 18 73 53  U..........,F.sS
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 03C0: 88 40 70 5A
>   F0 8F 3A 61   23 A3 90 BA E3 4D 6E 79  .@pZ..:a#....Mny
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 03D0: CF F4 0B 38
>   43 C9 4E C8   3D 84 69 C1 5C 63 3D 13  ...8C.N.=.i.\c=.
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 03E0: 37 29 BF C1
>   B4 40 0C 00   01 49 03 00 17 41 04 33  7)...@...I...A.3
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 03F0: 97 CA 08 57
>   A5 53 53 B7   88 89 C9 68 D7 3A F1 A9  ...W.SS....h.:..
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0400: 8F 1A D7 83
>   D6 47 B7 CE   0F 6D 5D 95 1C 53 A7 2F  .....G...m]..S./
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0410: 20 28 64 59
>   36 1A 53 07   AC 2A 4A 56 10 96 F8 76   (dY6.S..*JV...v
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0420: 66 52 76 77
>   3C A8 8C 7C   9B 01 BC C0 54 37 E4 06  fRvw<.......T7..
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0430: 01 01 00 2D
>   5B 86 66 EF   F0 A0 17 51 EC 0A 8C 9A  ...-[.f....Q....
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0440: C0 49 89 81
>   71 67 D9 CE   04 8D CF FA 5F 16 AA B8  .I..qg......_...
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0450: DF A0 57 FD
>   07 C1 4B 43   63 CC 58 DE C1 F3 E4 AF  ..W...KCc.X.....
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0460: C9 97 15 18
>   31 CB C3 8F   4C 52 40 6A BA F6 B3 B5  ....1...LR@j....
>
> 20:05:58,527 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0470: 7E F1 07 3D
>   0D 4F D6 60   A1 05 31 34 E5 F1 4D C5  ...=.O.`..14..M.
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0480: 7B 2E 79 22
>   46 4B 0A 4D   1A 66 E1 D9 32 E4 62 18  ..y"FK.M.f..2.b.
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0490: 5A 16 11 A4
>   5D 87 5E FA   48 BA DD 18 D6 5D 34 94  Z...].^.H....]4.
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 04A0: CB 77 99 2A
>   BE 0F 64 02   AD 3A DA 2A DE 54 7D 44  .w.*..d..:.*.T.D
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 04B0: 98 AA 8D 69
>   DE 27 8E 61   19 3B A1 C4 BC FA 2C 1E  ...i.'.a.;....,.
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 04C0: BA 1B 80 0C
>   74 4C A1 4A   B4 64 FB 25 37 91 21 69  ....tL.J.d.%7.!i
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 04D0: 7C BC C6 05
>   B4 59 76 EA   A8 94 F8 A3 1B 76 0E 90  .....Yv......v..
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 04E0: CF F7 9F 78
>   41 6A 15 63   44 4D 83 02 A6 E6 AB 55  ...xAj.cDM.....U
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 04F0: 65 8A B1 04
>   C8 31 B3 40   3C EB FA 63 69 1A DC FD  e....1.@<..ci...
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0500: 06 3B 82 B9
>   0F 93 5E 19   B0 B8 FF 81 E1 71 0B 28  .;....^......q.(
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0510: 96 D5 EC 12
>   B0 B8 75 20   35 6A 13 34 7C 29 FC 1E  ......u 5j.4.)..
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0520: 55 13 BA A5
>   55 47 83 EA   04 73 81 42 7C 37 D4 6E  U...UG...s.B.7.n
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0530: 1C 61 8E 0E
>   00 00 00                               .a.....
>
> 20:05:58,543 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1335
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) *** ServerHello,
>   TLSv1.2
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) RandomCookie:  GMT:
>   1515594702 bytes = { 12, 169, 165, 184, 202, 66, 172, 79, 205, 137,
>   120, 155, 84, 53, 96, 155, 171, 204, 27, 158, 110, 204, 30, 106, 51,
>   66, 45, 101 }
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Session ID:  {90,
>   86, 36, 206, 139, 127, 245, 138, 76, 16, 53, 64, 221, 106, 243, 210,
>   214, 220, 104, 177, 216, 228, 111, 248, 189, 86, 39, 66, 166, 127,
>   188, 52}
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Cipher Suite:
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Compression Method:
>   0
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Extension
>   renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection:
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ***
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) %% Initialized: 
>   [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) **
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) [read] MD5 and SHA1
>   hashes:  len = 81
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0000: 02 00 00 4D
>   03 03 5A 56   24 CE 0C A9 A5 B8 CA 42  ...M..ZV$......B
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0010: AC 4F CD 89
>   78 9B 54 35   60 9B AB CC 1B 9E 6E CC  .O..x.T5`.....n.
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0020: 1E 6A 33 42
>   2D 65 20 5A   56 24 CE 8B 7F F5 8A 4C  .j3B-e ZV$.....L
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0030: 10 35 40 DD
>   6A F3 D2 D6   DC 68 B1 D8 E4 6F F8 BD  .5@.j....h...o..
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0040: 56 27 42 A6
>   7F BC 34 C0   27 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  V'B...4.'.......
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0050: 00
>   .
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) *** Certificate
>   chain
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) chain [0] = [
>   20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) [ 20:05:58,559 INFO
>   [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   Version: V3 20:05:58,559 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   Subject: CN=135.250.139.109,
>   OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown 20:05:58,559
>   INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   Signature Algorithm:
>   SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
>   20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   modulus:
>   18206622876313961913465920255876027729157892284574140044521065825225620972157090031037231318432247624988589854629346868548662450561140228628094105077316003210772910559202590761643329483915308080029323068745529003201552913486724322045044639323117511481696978903235620797112083841189121546572562262734405423608611343450218803406314649817379769430519238039610049021362191216044363557781715622578876059062912058330038261137444365319119649343321033154783230060576311328288416895917133014261514056019516502888834493079172993213598359113270854116741458258927678033764530736483402808273460780474596794675317472631440616682409
>   20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   public exponent:
>   65537 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   Validity:
>   [From: Tue Jan 09 17:31:56 IST 2018, 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)                To: Wed Jan 09 17:31:56 IST
>   2019] 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   Issuer:
>   CN=135.250.139.109, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown,
>   C=Unknown 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   SerialNumber: [    775af1cf] 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Certificate Extensions: 1 20:05:58,559 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) [1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14
>   Criticality=false 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   SubjectKeyIdentifier [ 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) KeyIdentifier [ 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0000: B6 C2 19 D4 9C FD 3F EA   54 87 B7 42 E1
>   0D 8A 95  ......?.T..B....
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0010: F8 99 AE ED
>   ....
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ] 20:05:58,559 INFO
>   [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ] 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ] 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA] 20:05:58,559 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)   Signature: 20:05:58,559 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0000: 5D 0E 55 1F C3 1B B5 72   37 F7
>   2F EF 1D 85 AD D2  ].U....r7./.....
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0010: 8C 92 81 BF
>   54 6C 3E E2   64 30 05 D8 77 AE D0 19  ....Tl>.d0..w...
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0020: B7 79 6D 1F
>   9A AC D7 92   79 72 67 82 FB CC F2 00  .ym.....yrg.....
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0030: 37 2F 0A E9
>   26 34 FF 37   83 DC 38 C0 5B 6D A8 E5  7/..&4.7..8.[m..
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0040: D4 9B A4 E5
>   AE 77 EA 93   12 FD 00 9A 4A 0A 9C 63  .....w......J..c
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0050: E4 67 9F F1
>   05 BD D5 C7   DF 0E FC 17 30 50 92 83  .g..........0P..
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0060: 33 00 9B E9
>   A1 90 E4 32   C4 00 76 A9 05 36 07 6C  3......2..v..6.l
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0070: 00 19 65 0C
>   2B 8C 89 28   FF E4 F0 67 B2 2C 6B D3  ..e.+..(...g.,k.
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0080: 9B 48 DB 18
>   10 EF F5 BF   3B 9C D0 19 F1 1E 59 39  .H......;.....Y9
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0090: 36 04 F4 D9
>   91 25 77 3C   95 13 AC A9 61 3F E9 B2  6....%w<....a?..
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00A0: AC 66 F2 95
>   2C F5 3A C2   8A BC AC C6 B3 68 AC A5  .f..,.:......h..
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00B0: 33 72 4C 88
>   97 F7 50 1D   70 5B FD 1D FF 19 F4 18  3rL...P.p[......
>
> 20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00C0: 1A 1B 3D 8D
>   57 4B 23 F1   7F 3A 55 95 1E 82 F6 D2  ..=.WK#..:U.....
>   20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00D0: DD EB 9B 99
>   BE 2C 46 18   73 53 88 40 70 5A F0 8F  .....,F.sS.@pZ..
>   20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00E0: 3A 61 23 A3
>   90 BA E3 4D   6E 79 CF F4 0B 38 43 C9  :a#....Mny...8C.
>   20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 00F0: 4E C8 3D 84
>   69 C1 5C 63   3D 13 37 29 BF C1 B4 40  N.=.i.\c=.7)...@
>   20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  20:05:58,559 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ]
>   20:05:58,559 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) ***
>   20:05:58,590 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) %% Invalidated: 
>   [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
>   20:05:58,590 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description =
>   certificate_unknown
>   20:05:58,590 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
>   20:05:58,590 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) [Raw write]: length
>   = 7
>   20:05:58,606 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) 0000: 15 03 03 00
>   02 02 2E
>   20:05:58,606 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, called closeSocket()
>   20:05:58,606 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, handling exception:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   20:05:58,606 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, called close()
>   20:05:58,606 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)
>   http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1, called closeInternal(true)
>   20:05:58,606 ERROR [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) failed to turn code into token:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

Comment: It's not related to the Java version. We need to check you're really using this cacerts file by adding this JVM option at the JBOSS startup : -Djavax.net.debug=all . Come back with the new logs then.

Comment: @EugèneAdell Added more log details after adding your suggestion.

Comment: it's incomplete as we don't see the JSSE initialization and the cacerts loading. What we can see, anyway, is that the certificate returned by the server is for CN=135.250.139.109 . Are you calling https://135.250.139.109  or a domain name ( I mean an IP or a domain name) ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell I am using ip address of the server

Comment: @EugèneAdell I am using ip address as my virtual machine dont have domain name

Comment: ok, you can do it this way. Please provide the beginning of your debug log, we need to see which truststore is loaded during the initialization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162908/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-eugene-adell).

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, could you add the solution in this thread, since I have similar problem and I'm curious how you've solved it.

Comment: @Georgi As I remember it's a bug in Java updating Java with 1.8.51+ wil resolve the issue. Which version you r using ?

Comment: Hmm ... it might be, I didn't think about it .. mine is 1.8.0_172.

Comment: @Georgi Check if your both Java version same in my case certificate generated in Open JDK and trying to import in Oracle JDK

Comment: I guess this is not the case for me, the version difference is minor - trusted store is generated and certs imported on "1.8.0_181", while the server JVM  is 1.8.0_172, but both are Oracle implementations

Comment: @Georgi Better we should discuss this issue outside stakcoverflow ,Gmail will be fine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179558/discussion-between-georgi-and-subodh-joshi).